# Rxjava retryWhen with delay not triggering retry

Tags: observable, delay, rx-java2, retrywhen

```
Observable<Integer> call = Observable.create(emitter -> {
    emitter.onNext(1);
    emitter.onError(new Throwable("Error"));
});

call
.retryWhen(throwableObservable -> throwableObservable)
.subscribe(integer -> System.out.println(integer), throwable -> System.out.println(throwable.getMessage()));
```

This code is working as expected, (constantly printing '1'), but if I change it to:

```
.retryWhen(throwableObservable -> throwableObservable.delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
```

It will only print '1' once and not retry.

Comment: You introduced asynchrony in the delay process. Are you waiting long enough to see the retry? [Recommended reading](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#schedulers).

Comment: It should print '1' every second (with the .delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS) included), but it prints only once and the retry does not get triggered.

Comment: Works for me: https://gist.github.com/akarnokd/acff7ab937838467d6b8da90d1974900

Comment: ok understood now and working, so the first option is just faster and it's not needed to pass on to the main thread, with delay, the main thread gains focus and stops the program, correct?.

Comment: The sleep prevents the main thread from premature exit which stops RxJava's schedulers by default. If you have an android or swing application, there is no need to sleep.